# Как правильно записать json в mysql используя pymysql?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pymysql

уважаемые знатоки, имеется контейнер с mysql и словарь содержащий данные из git, словарь конвертирован в json Не могу понять как записать данный файл в БД и как сделать это правильно, так чтобы ключ ушел в один столбик а значение в другой

Я в python'e всего неделю, жду жесткой но конструктивной критики и прошу у вас ссылки, ибо все что я накопал в инете мне не дало и дюйма решения нехватки данной информации

```
import mysql.connector
import json
import mysql
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
from PythonGIT import Lastwords

#make json data from Lastwords
json_send = json.dumps(Lastwords, indent=4)
#print(json_send)
#make connect to DB
def create_connection(host_name, host_port, user_name, user_password, db_name):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host_name,
            port=host_port,
            user=user_name,
            passwd=user_password,
            database=db_name
        )
        print("Connection to MySQL DB successful")
    except Error as e:
        print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")

    return connection
connection = create_connection("localhost", 3306, "root", "My:S3cr3t/", "jiragit")
cursor = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
#send json to DB
# json_send
# sql = ""
with cursor:
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jiragit ( JiraTicket TEXT, EVENT TEXT) VALUES (%s,%s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, json_send)




connection.commit()
#Close connections
connection.close()
print("Connect close")
```

Json

```
"MID-4151": [
        [
            "7e5ac616df12ed6fb344c8cf1817e5a9f4ee6c34",
            "kurbat_kanstantsin"
        ],
        [
            "1f201a2c10e12f3781afb7cf52e0b24530ee22da",
            "kurbat_kanstantsin"
        ],
        [
            "e473e1b77857fa2ef6e34c7f4117e48d1149cb4c",
            "kkurbat"
        ],
        [
            "41085f9b17a02b1773da26291573be51dd7c44fc",
            "kkurbat"
        ]
    ],
    "IN-2558": [
        [
            "18a382da0903bc4c1aa8dbdc09423e6120293409",
            "artem"
        ],
        [
            "f28fee874a30b854536ace422f401181b70d6f28",
            "artem"
        ],
        [
            "c5f4b78781e1495c21fc02bf5a696835a1eab431",
            "artem"
        ],
        [
            "313b300d2e4ae3eb17f62cf2acd6d00713df0ca9",
            "artem"
        ],
        [
            "2a7a1a6517ffb71f5a0d1da3cf18bd6c511102d0",
            "artem"
        ]
    ],
```

dict

```
{'CE-2019': [('a3873de1b37c14ea2d9379387026da6188cdd5d2', 'Ivan Vdovin'), ('327f430f39dd2db0c4ad9bb8fa599d7be7b1b4df', 'dmitrykoptik')], 'Merge_or_Fix': [('467f483d9fac6f2a587065ad6c3eeb4557b430bc', 'Stanislav Dudkov aka D2269'), ('1565ec5429da1156b593ea16658409288176edbe', 'Petr Sabaleuski'), ('2bda4e434cbe9271e9719feb16d27b04058d689f', 'Petr Sabaleuski'), ('caf6ee5460645a2691aeb03693a94327fd6833e7', 'Alex_Odinokov'),
```

Comment: Так вы покажите как выглядит ваш `JSON` и как выглядит таблица в БД. Чтобы было понятно - что и куда нужно положить. Одного кода недостаточно.

Comment: И соответственно покажите конечное состояние данных в таблице после импорта показанного JSON. Да, версию MySQL **точную** тоже надо указать. PS. На питоне задачу решать не надо - просто отдай JSON, и запрос сам всё разложит куда нужно.

Comment: @Akina, Добавил данные в пост

Comment: @CrazyElf Добавил данные в пост

Comment: Показанный JSON не является валидным. Должно быть внешнее обрамление скобками, и не должно быть последней запятой. А DICT так и вовсе оборван на середине. Не показано конечное состояние данных в таблице MySQL, да и сама структура таблицы. Не указана точная версия MySQL.

Comment: Json сгенерирован python'oм и является валидным, это примеры данных заключающихся в нем

Comment: @Akina У меня нет проблем с Json у меня есть вопрос как его засунуть в БД сохраняя пару ключ:значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Вопрос:

| JiraTicket | EVENT |
| --- | --- |
| MID-4151 | [["7e5ac616df12ed6fb344c8cf1817e5a9f4ee6c34", "kurbat_kanstantsin"], ["1f201a2c10e12f3781afb7cf52e0b24530ee22da", "kurbat_kanstantsin"], ["e473e1b77857fa2ef6e34c7f4117e48d1149cb4c", "kkurbat"], ["41085f9b17a02b1773da26291573be51dd7c44fc", "kkurbat"]] |
| IN-2558 | [["18a382da0903bc4c1aa8dbdc09423e6120293409", "artem"], ["f28fee874a30b854536ace422f401181b70d6f28", "artem"], ["c5f4b78781e1495c21fc02bf5a696835a1eab431", "artem"], ["313b300d2e4ae3eb17f62cf2acd6d00713df0ca9", "artem"], ["2a7a1a6517ffb71f5a0d1da3cf18bd6c511102d0", "artem"]] |

*Вы Так представляете себе таблицу или как-то иначе?*

```sql
create table test_scm.jira_git
(
    JiraTicket text,
    EVENT      json
);
```

## UPD:

### Вот что-то такое попробуйте:

- Библиотека для работы с БД не та что у Вас но тоже хорошая, а принципы работы с ними идентичные.
- И, кстати, Вам правильно сказали на счет того, что json у вас не валидный.

```py
from pymysql.cursors import Cursor
from pymysql import connect
import simplejson as json

conn = connect(
    host='localhost',
    port=3306,
    user='user',
    password='********',
    autocommit=True,
    database='db'
)

cur: Cursor = conn.cursor()

# В случае если Ваш JSON уже словарь
data = {
    "MID-4151": [
        [
            "7e5ac616df12ed6fb344c8cf1817e5a9f4ee6c34",
            "kurbat_kanstantsin"
        ],
        [
            "1f201a2c10e12f3781afb7cf52e0b24530ee22da",
            "kurbat_kanstantsin"
        ],
        [
            "e473e1b77857fa2ef6e34c7f4117e48d1149cb4c",
            "kkurbat"
        ],
        [
            "41085f9b17a02b1773da26291573be51dd7c44fc",
            "kkurbat"
        ]
    ],
    "IN-2558": [
        [
            "18a382da0903bc4c1aa8dbdc09423e6120293409",
            "artem"
        ],
        [
            "f28fee874a30b854536ace422f401181b70d6f28",
            "artem"
        ],
        [
            "c5f4b78781e1495c21fc02bf5a696835a1eab431",
            "artem"
        ],
        [
            "313b300d2e4ae3eb17f62cf2acd6d00713df0ca9",
            "artem"
        ],
        [
            "2a7a1a6517ffb71f5a0d1da3cf18bd6c511102d0",
            "artem"
        ]
    ]
}

# В случае если Ваш JSON - строка - воспользуйтесь `json.loads()`


def prepare_data(item):
    key, val = item
    return key, json.dumps(val)


cur.executemany(
    "insert into test_scm.jira_git ( JiraTicket, EVENT ) values (%s, %s) ",
    [
        *map(prepare_data, data.items())
    ]
)
```

Comment: Да, конечно, просто не понимаю как к этому прийти и где взять инфу по этому случаю

Comment: Это вырезка из json для понимания структуры данных

Comment: Доброго дня, сделал как вы подсказали, но все равно выдает ошибку что словарь json как строка
загрузил пример всех данных в гит https://gitlab.com/Vladislav.Skibenko/jiragit

Comment: Ошибка след 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vsi\int\sfdevops_metrics\.project\step1\PyMysql.py", line 39, in <module>
    *map(prepare_data, json_send.items())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @Miekrif, думаю, что проблема заключается в том, что Вы пытаетесь обработать JSON как строку. Ковертируете его в словарь с помощью `json.loads()` или прочтите файл с помочью `json.load(open(<you/file/path.json>))`

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь, все получилось, подскажите пожалуйста чтива для получения подобных знаний и повышение уровня в python

Comment: @Miekrif, как показывает практика, самым полезным чтивом по python (после базвого уровня) становится чтение доков по либам, а самой результативной практикой (ИМХО) написание кода, разбор ситуаций возникших в процессе его написания. Добавьте себе в закладки вот этот сайт https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/. Это неплохой справичник на каждый день.